# Arrows in branch window on smartgit

Tags: git, user-interface, branch, smartgit, arrows

I'm a Smartgit user and I don't understand what the little right arrows in the "Branches" window mean. They point to branches, but only to some of them.

I attach a screenshot. The arrows I'm referring to are circled in red.

Thanks.

**Screenshot of Smartgit UI:**

[image: Screenshot of Smartgit UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filled-in triangle is your currently checked-out branch.

The empty triangles are local branches that have not yet been pushed to an upstream repository (eg: `git push --set-upstream origin branch-name`). They server as a nice little warning that some of your work is only available locally: use caution when deleting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can an empty arrow be under "origin" in the accepted screenshot? Shouldn't those branches be in the upstream repository by definition?

Comment: The empty triangles are branches which are located at the same commit as your HEAD.